# Multiple instances of react-select dropdown connected from redux-toolkit store

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-select

I'm creating a react-select dropdown with a list of available fonts.  The data is stored in a fontSlice of my redux-toolkit store.  This works for one instance, it gives me the list of available fonts, and the ability to "save" back up to store which one the user selects.  Now I want to create several instances of this same dropdown for different font categories, like body, headings, etc.  There may be 5 or so of these categories.

What is the best practice for achieving this?  I don't want the fetching from the store to be too expensive, as there are quite a lot of fonts there.  I've never really used useMemo or useCallback, would that help me here?  I need to keep each selected value separate from eachother, but the available options would be the same on each.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways of implementing this, but since I assume you intend to use the font data across the app it makes sense to store it in redux and use it on the components you need using selectors. I've created an example in codesandbox that mocks the fetching of some fonts and renders dropdowns to select font values. Here it would be very easy to add more font values by modifying the file fontsSlice and add new value keys.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-moon-qmhk6d?file=/src/App.js

You could also keep the state (selected font values) in the component, but based on the usecase it seem's like it's data that you intend to use across the app.